# How to override website security certificate to remove error?

Tags: excel, ssl, ms-word, ms-office, onedrive

This has happened to Microsoft OneDrive a few days ago many people are having this problem. When you go to save a file in Word or Excel it says ""There is a problem with the Web site's security certificate. Save to retry your upload." It will save new file names but it will not upload updates to existing files. Is there a way to disable checking for the security certificate or put a fake one or accept the old one so that OneDrive can be functional again?

Answer (score 0):

This thread has two potential solutions that seem to work, namely:

- saving to the onedrive directory on your computer rather than online
- unchecking a "save" option in the onedrive app settings (Although having done this, onedrive seems to have forgotten that I have office 365...)

This seems to be working - at the moment...

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles/one-drive-sync-error-upload-failed-website/d41e891d-d257-42cc-acdf-92f4d31b746e